# iOS - cordova plugin tagmanager error

Tags: ios, cordova, google-tag-manager

I'm having this error during build phase of cordova project due to cordova-plugin-tag-manager:

```
Plugins/com.jareddickson.cordova.tag-manager/CDVTagManager.m:145:42: No visible @interface for 'CDVPluginResult' declares the selector 'toSuccessCallbackString:'

Plugins/com.jareddickson.cordova.tag-manager/CDVTagManager.m:145:42: No visible @interface for 'CDVPluginResult' declares the selector 'toErrorCallbackString:'
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution..

Must modify tagmanager plugin, class `CDVTagManager.m`

```
replace: [self writeJavascript:[commandResult toErrorCallbackString:callbackID]];

with: [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:commandResult callbackId:callbackID];

in methods: successWithMessage y failWithMessage
```